# AWS Amazon - Sign in Loop Stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

So I've been using AWS amazon for a couple of years now.

However, suddenly when i sign-in, i get to this verification part and they send the verification code to my email and i receive the code.

So i type in the code that i received, and i end up back to the sign-in page. So i Login and the same thing happens again over and over again.

I'm not able to go to my dashboard whatsoever, it just keeps going back to sign-in and verification page.

I tried the following already:

- Changed my password
- Clear browser and cache
- Used a another pc
- Used a different browser
- I've contacted amazon aws, but still not getting any answers

Anyone encountered this before and have a solution?

D

Answer (score 4):

I am also having this problem and after contacting AWS support they said its a known issue:

> There is currently an ongoing issue with our login screen that we are working diligently to resolve in a timely manner.
>
> I don't have an estimated time for when it will be fixed, but I've added your account information to our issue tracker to ensure that your access is restored as soon as possible.