# AWS Amazon - Sign in Loop Stuck again

Tags: amazon-web-services

This issue has started coming up for me. Signing in using 2FA and solving the Captcha just sends me back to the login form again when trying to access my AWS dashboard. Doesn't matter which browser I use. Originally came up a few years ago: [AWS Amazon - Sign in Loop Stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768005/aws-amazon-sign-in-loop-stuck)

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's an AWS support question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

[This post helped me](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=39465458).

I use [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) to auto-type my email address. It seems that the AWS login form has now been rigged with some sort of detection if this field is filled too quickly that flags you as a bot.

I mean, some sort of feedback would be nice "*sorry, you've still got that whiff of **bot** about you, we'll just need to do a few more of these if you don't mind...*" but no, let's just dump the user into an endless loop questioning their sanity.

Anyway, typing out my email instead got me in.

Comment: The same is happening when using dashlane. Interestingly, auto-filling the password doesn't trigger the infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using correct password and entering right CAPTCHA keywords.
Use incognito and vpn and good internet.
I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.